# Три зависимых списка на jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Нужен был зависимый выпадающий список, нашел похожее решение с городами и областями.
Не знаю, как сделать, чтобы от выбранного **сорта**, менялось не только количество, **но и значения длины**?

В данный момент меняется количество от выбранного сорта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот файл данных:**

```
<?php
$city = array (
  'Местные розы' => array (
    11 => '11 шт. (минимум)',
    25 => '25 шт.',
    51 => '51 шт.',
    101 => '101 шт.',
  ),
  'Эквадорские розы' => array (
    25 => '25 шт. (минимум)',
    51 => '51 шт.',
    76 => '76 шт.',
    101 => '101 шт.',
  ),
);
?>
```

**В самом начале файла:**

```
<?php
require_once('city.php'); // подключаем список с городами

$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';

// возвращаем список городов
if ($action == 'getCity')
{
    if (isset($city[$_GET['region']]))
    {
        echo json_encode($city[$_GET['region']]); // возвраащем данные в JSON формате;
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array('Выберите количество'));
    }

    exit;
}

// выводим пришедшие данные
if ($action == 'postResult')
{
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars(print_r($_POST, true)) . '</pre>';
    exit;
}
?>
```

**javascript:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
        function loadCity(select)
        {
            var citySelect = $('select[name="city"]');
            citySelect.attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // делаем список городов не активным

            // послыаем AJAX запрос, который вернёт список городов для выбранной области
            $.getJSON('index.php', {action:'getCity', region:select.value}, function(cityList){

                citySelect.html(''); // очищаем список городов

                // заполняем список городов новыми пришедшими данными
                $.each(cityList, function(i){
                    citySelect.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + this + '</option>');
                });

                citySelect.removeAttr('disabled'); // делаем список городов активным

            });
        }
    // ]]>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте еще один уровень вложенности в массиве, остальная серверная часть не изменится

```
$city = array (
  'Местные розы' => array (
    'quantity' => array (
      11 => '11 шт. (минимум)',
      25 => '25 шт.',
      51 => '51 шт.',
      101 => '101 шт.',
    ),
    'lengths' => array (
      70 => '70 см',
      90 => '90 см',
    ),
  ),
  'Эквадорские розы' => array (
    'quantity' => array (
      25 => '25 шт. (минимум)',
      51 => '51 шт.',
      76 => '76 шт.',
      101 => '101 шт.',
    ),
    'lengths' => array (
      50 => '50 см',
      80 => '80 см',
    ),
  ),
);
```

На стороне js полученные два массива `cityList.quantity` и `cityList.lengths` заполняете в соответствующие списки (подобно тому как вы заполняете `citySelect`)

Я бы сделал так: внутри обработчика `getJSON(...)` написал бы следующее

```
// Перебираем массив с ключами в виде имен выпадающих списков
$.each(cityList, function(field) {
    // Получаем нужный список, очищаем его и включаем
    var fieldElement = $('select[name="' + field + '"]')
        .empty()
        .removeAttr('disabled');
    // Перебираем массив со значениями пунктов списка
    $.each(this, function(i) {
        // Собственно наполняем список зачениями
        fieldElement.append('<option value="' + i + '">' +
            this + '</option>');
    });
});
```

При этом селекты, соответствующие количеству и размерам следует назвать в соответствии с ключами массивов, которые отдает сервер (то есть `quantity` и `lengths`).

Comment: Можно подробней, если не сложно. Никак не разберусь...

Comment: @bakusite C чем именно? C JS?

Comment: Да, с заполнением списков, это в JS?

Comment: @bakusite дополнил ответ